# What does "poll 235.000 ms took 125.000 ms: 1 events" mean when debugging asyncio code?

Tags: python-3.7, python-asyncio

I enabled debug mode in my Python `asyncio` code, and I get log messages that look like:

```
asyncio (DEBUG) | poll 235.000 ms took 125.000 ms: 1 events
asyncio (DEBUG) | poll 250.000 ms took 125.000 ms: 1 events
asyncio (DEBUG) | poll 250.000 ms took 109.000 ms: 1 events
```

I don't understand what they mean. Is this good or bad?

Are these log messages indicating either of the conditions mentioned in the [asyncio development guide](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-dev.html#debug-mode)?

> - The execution time of the I/O selector is logged if it takes too long to perform an I/O operation.
> - Callbacks taking longer than 100ms are logged.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This message is logged in `BaseEventLoop._run_once()`. It is generated during an iteration of the event loop.

- The first number (`poll 235.000 ms`) is the selector timeout.
- The second number (`took 125.000 ms`) is the actual amount of time the selector took.
- The third number (`1 events`) is the number of events the selector returned.

For these particular messages, everything appears to be functioning normally.